# Wordpress: redirect from B to A has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: wordpress, cors, cross-domain

First of all those similars questions does not fit my situation, I've tried all the `.htaccess` solutions already.

I have a WordPress site (A) which handles the reservation form, and the form submit to another server (B) which handle the data (as well as follow up customer and payment), after the submission success I need to redirect to thanks-you page in A. but this happens

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load B. Redirect from 'B' to 'A/thanks-you/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'A' is therefore not allowed access.`

I understand that by setting the response header from B will fix the issue, but I don't have access to it. (Already tested)

So my question is it possible to work on server A to fix this?

Thanks for all the comments and answer.

Answer (score 0):

This CORS issue is troubling many, try below option it may help you.

Just changed Origin URL from http to https and issue resolved in my case. There is another way to fix an issue too. 
REF : https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/

Comment: check if you enabled CDN and server level settings for CORS restriction.

Comment: What CDN? My question is not about CDN.

Comment: CDN also may be block cross domain

Answer (score 0):

just add below line into your .htaccess file.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```